# SBS 2003 no network connection and acting strangely a bunch of Event ID 13568

Tags: windows-event-log, windows-sbs-2003, journal

I've got an SBS 2003 Standard server and it was running fine until earlier today when it was rebooted, after the reboot it has no network connection, I can't seem to right click on a lot of stuff and get dialog boxes, I can't launch IE, it's acting extremely strange. We are dead in the water at this point. I checked the event logs and noticed  we're getting a ton of Event ID's 13568.

I thought it was a Journal Wrap error, and while I was going to try to fix it using this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290762

I can't even do that because after I set the D4 value, then went to restart NTFRS from command prompt and I got the following: System Error 1059 has occurred. Circular service dependency was specified.

That is where I'm at and haven't been able to figure anything else out.

ALso, I've posted this on EE, there are some screens of event logs and such there: http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/SBS_Small_Business_Server/Q_27969593.html

Comment: Have you run a chkdsk /f?  That sounds like a corrupted filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been abandoned, but I wanted to answer it since I just fixed this problem on my server and I HATE it when someone has the same problem and it never gets answered!

See the article below. Had to change the RPC service login to Local System. Once I did that and rebooted, everything came back up!

http://blogs.technet.com/b/perfguru/archive/2008/07/15/services-not-starting-after-installing-service-pack-on-windows-2003-server.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.